# Does the Chrome Bluetooth API work on Windows Mobile?

Tags: google-chrome, installation, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-chrome-app

TLDR:  Can the Chrome Bluetooth API be used on the Windows mobile platform?

I'm on a quest to find a solution for bluetooth connectivity across various platforms.

We plan on having native iOS and Android versions for our app, and a web app for other platforms (limited time and budget).

The setup of our product requires a one-time bluetooth connection to configure a wireless connection if necessary.  This is fine for the iOS and Android versions of the app, but presents a problem for desktops/laptops or Windows mobile users.

The option for our device to act as an accesspoint has been considered, but it's not a very user-friendly solution.  It needs to be easy enough your grandmother can set it up, and switching to another wireless network doesn't qualify.

In my research, I've come across the Chrome Bluetooth API available in Chrome Browsers starting in version 37.  I'm wondering how accessible this would be for, say, the Windows mobile crowd.  Or laptop and desktops running Windows, ChromeOS, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, that api is not available to the web, it is available for Chrome Packaged Apps, which are published to and installed from the Chrome Web Store (they do not have a URL you can just visit).

Second, I do not think that Chrome Apps are available for windows mobile, though they are supported for all the desktop platforms.  (Make sure that the bluetooth api support you need is fully support across all platforms, though, since there are some limitations).

Finally, there is ongoing work for an upcoming [web-bluetooth](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth) api which will be available for the open web -- but that is some ways away.

Best of luck.